# Laravel Routing adding template name

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a blade template called by Lodge.upload. Within that template I have the following code:

```
<form name="app" action="storeSummons" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

In my route files I have this:

```
Route::post('/storeSummons',[\App\Http\Controllers\LodgesController::class,'storeSummons'])->name('storeSummons');
```

When I try to post from this simple form (only two fields) I get the error

> The POST method is not supported for route Lodge.uploads/storeSummons. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

The route is clearly marked as storeSummons with no reference to the template name or it's route.

I have tried clearing the cache, routes, views but it still insists on adding this to the route. The group in question has only auth as middleware added.

It is driving me mad and I have checked for the route being duplicated without success.

Comment: we always suggest using the route name not the path so `action="{{ route('storeSummons') }}"` ... this generates a full URL (absolute) not just a relative path ... what you have currently is saying submit this to a path relative to the current path that is displaying this form, which does not dictate that the path is off the root of the site or any particular "folder"/path segment

Comment: You should also add the CSRF field here the doc : [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#csrf-field)

Answer (score 0):

When I called the open form, I should have added `action="{{route('storeSummons')}}"`.

Answer (score -2):

I'll assist you in troubleshooting the "POST method not supported" error in your Laravel application. Here's a comprehensive response, combining insights from expert feedback and addressing potential causes:

**Understanding the Error:**

- Incorrect Route or Method: The error indicates a mismatch between
  the form's submission method and the defined route.
- Missing CSRF Token: Laravel requires a valid CSRF token for POST
  requests to protect against cross-site request forgery attacks.

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

- Verify Route Definition:

  - Ensure the route is defined as a POST route:
    `Route::post('/storeSummons', ...)`.
  - Check for any conflicting routes with the same path or name.
  - If the route is within a group, confirm the group's middleware
    configuration.
- Include CSRF Token:

  - Add the `@csrf` directive within the form:

    `<form name="app" action="storeSummons" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">@csrf</form>`
- Inspect Route Caching:

  - Clear the route cache: `php artisan route:clear`.
  - If using a caching mechanism, clear the cache there as well.
- Review Middleware:

  - Examine middleware applied to the route or group, ensuring they don't interfere with - POST requests.
- Check Browser Developer Tools:

  - Inspect network requests for correct path and method.
  - Look for any errors or warnings indicating issues.

Comment: "combining insights from expert feedback and addressing potential causes:"  .. oh yea, where did you find all of this? sure seems like an AI generated answer

Comment: AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.

Comment: haters gonna. AI will replace this website any ways. @lagbox

Comment: it is the policy of the website to not allow AI generated content ... has nothing to do with "haters" ... if people wanted to get answers from an AI that was incorrect they would ask the AI, but they come here to ask people, not AI ... not sure why that is difficult to understand